# How to make GRUB work again?

Tags: grub2

I installed Ubuntu and then Windows 8. How can I make GRUB work again so that I can choose which system I want to boot?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this should help : https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Cheers

Comment: This worked for me after an update had GRUB stop working.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you need to update the bootloader from Ubuntu. You can do this by booting a live-ubuntu to make the neccessary changes there: [ubuntu-community](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RecoveringUbuntuAfterInstallingWindows)

Please also have a look [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-8-64-bit-system-uefi-supported) for specific configuration you might need.